# Google Script triggers not running

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a Google Script for which most of my triggers are failing to run. I'm trying to have a couple of onEdits, a few form submits, and some time-triggers...preferably programmatic where possible. The only one that currently works is an installed onOpen trigger...but I'd rather that one be programmatic if possible. Nearly-identical test functions running on other spreadsheets (with less scripting) run just fine

I've tried to break it down to troubleshoot, getting as far as this:

```
function onOpen() {Logger.log('something');}
```

This should put the word "something" into the log when I open/refresh the spreadsheet, but nothing happens. I feel like the trigger issues are related, but I can't figure out how to address them. All functions work when manually run (except onEdit, due to the lack of event). What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using console.log instead of Logger.log? The stackdriver is more persistent than the Logger

Comment: Hadn't thought of that, thanks. However...all the errors I see in the console are things that cropped up while I was tweaking other things...but nothing that indicates while triggers aren't working. I've had three time triggers going for a couple of hours, which should have fired several times by now, all of which are functions which work when started manually. If there were console logs from this, I'd have a _ton_ of errors

Comment: This may be a bug in Apps Script.  I know of one other person who has reported a lot of failures in their On Form Submit trigger.